# doubt in countably infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $E$ be a countably infinite set. If $E_1$ is a subset of $E$ with one element fewer than that of $E$, and similarly $E_2$ is a subset of $E_1$ with one element fewer than that of $E_1$, then if we consider the limit of $E_n$ as $n \to \infty$, will it be empty?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this question depends on how the elements are removed. Suppose that $E=\mathbb{N}$. Lets sketch two situations

- $E_n = \{n\}$. In this case we have $\bigcup_nE_{n} = \mathbb{N}$, thus $E\setminus\bigcup_nE_{n}=\mathbb{N}\setminus \mathbb{N} = \emptyset$.
- $E_n = \{2n\}$. In this case we have $\bigcup_nE_{n} = 2\mathbb{N}$, thus the remaining set is $\mathbb{N}\setminus2\mathbb{N} = \{1,3,5,\ldots\}$.

Comment: what does that N\2N mean?

Comment: N-2N? you mean?

Comment: @Mukil "$\setminus$" is more commonly used for set subtraction than "$-$"; the reason being, sometimes we want to consider $\{x-y: x\in A, y\in B\}$, and this is natural to denote "$A-B$."

Comment: thank you so much both of you^^

Comment: Marc is just saying let the set be the set of positive integers. Then remove $2,$ then remove $4,$, then remove $6,$ etc. If you continue doing this "infinitely many times", you will still have all the odd positive integers left in the set.

Comment: Or E = N.  Remove 5, then 6, then 7.  The remaining set will be {1,2,3,4} with 4 elements.  Can set it up with 0, any finite, or infinitely countable elements left.

Comment: Note that this highlights an important aspect of infinite constructions (sometimes called **supertasks**) - the need to be completely clear, even when there is no ambiguity in the finite versions.